# Testing static methods in a parameterised test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, static

I have a class which is an implementation of a topological sort on a directed acyclic graph. There are two methods in this class:

1. public static int[] sort(int[][] dag) - takes a 2-dimensional array representing a DAG as a parameter and returns an array of the ordered nodes
2. private static void visit - that visits carries out a depth-first search and is used in the sort method

I have to write a JUnit test to test the code with different inputs. I am relatively new to JUnit testing and I not sure how to approach this problem. I guess I need to write a parameterised test but how can I test the static method sort(int[][] dag)? Do I need any mock objects? I'd appreciate it if you can give me some insights.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use Parameterized testing in JUNIT. Through which you can give multiple combination of inputs.According to your requirement You can change.One more interesting randomizedtesting we have recently using our project which will generate input randomly.Please have a look
https://github.com/randomizedtesting/randomizedtesting

```
 private int fInput;

  private int fExpected;

 @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }  
           });
    }
```

Also look into below post
[static junit example](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/11/testing-and-mocking-of-static-methods-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

As you are new, some guiding thoughts:

- I would suggest to go with ordinary JUnit tests initially. Meaning: you write a lot of small test cases, and each test consists of these 3 elements: 1) you prepare an input array that should test a certain aspect of your sort algorithm 2) you invoke your sort() with that input 3) you check that you either receive exactly that result you expect on your input; or you check that some expected exception is thrown (for example when passing in a malformed input array).
- as said, you start with many small tests, one for each different "contract element" of your sort method; or with a "white box view" - one test per possible path within your production code.

  - when that works, and you are convinced that you understand how to use/create those "simple" tests, then you look into advanced features such as parameterized tests.
- and when you want to do really cool things, you can Google for QuickCheck... A very different but powerful approach to testing - coming from other languages, but also possible with java.

Finally: you only test your public sort() method, you avoid testing private implementation details.